# Change edges' arrow style with tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-feynman

How can I change the edges' arrow style? For example with a fermion line:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\tikzfeynmanset{ fermion/.style = {???} }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [right of a] (b);
    \diagram*{ (a) -- [fermion](b) };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)) does not use 'arrows' in the sense of the 'arrows' library from Ti*k*Z; instead, it decorates the path using a triangle:

```
/tikz/decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position 0.5 with {
    \node[
      transform shape,
      xshift=-0.5mm,
      fill,
      inner sep=〈some distance〉,
      draw=none,
      isosceles triangle
    ] { };
  },
},
/tikz/decorate=true,
```

In particular, you can change the shape from `isosceles triangle` to whatever you want.  Alternatively, it is also possible to use the `\arrow` command within the decoration (refer to the Ti*k*Z manual for the exact details).

I have illustrated two cases below.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\tikzfeynmanset{
  fermion1/.style={
    /tikz/postaction={
      /tikz/decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.5 with {
          \node[
            transform shape,
            xshift=-0.5mm,
            fill,
            dart tail angle=100,
            inner sep=1.3pt,
            draw=none,
            dart
          ] { };
        },
      },
      /tikz/decorate=true,
    },
  },
  fermion2/.style={
    /tikz/postaction={
      /tikz/decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.5 with {
          \arrow{>[length=6pt, width=5pt]};
        },
      },
      /tikz/decorate=true,
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  a -- [fermion1] b -- [fermion2] {c, d},
};
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Since you probably want to change the fermion style completely, then I would recommend creating a new fermion style instead of overwriting the default one.  Having said that, have a look at [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586)'s answer as he is going even more general than I am in this answer!  He is modifying one of the underlying styles in Ti*k*Z-Feynman (the `with arrow` style) so that the arrows are changed for *all* particles.

Comment: This is also a great starting point for further customizations! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The arrow tip in the middle of the lines are placed using a decoration from the `decoration.markings` library. I think you need to specify a new decoration altogether, for example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\tikzfeynmanset{ fermion/.style = {
   decoration={
     markings,
     mark=at position 0.5
          with {\arrow[xshift=2mm]{Stealth[red,width=3mm,length=4mm]}}
     },
   postaction=decorate}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [right=of a] (b);
    \diagram*{ (a) -- [fermion](b) };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

More generally, `fermion` and other styles with an arrow in the middle use a style called `with arrow`, that is defined by `tikz-feynman`. If you want the same arrow tip for all of these, you could modify that style instead. Not sure if [JP-Ellis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26980/jp-ellis), the package author, intended for people to do that though.

[image]

```
\documentclass[review]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\tikzfeynmanset{ with arrow/.style = {
   decoration={
     markings,
     mark=at position 0.5
          with {\arrow[xshift=2mm]{Stealth[red,width=3mm,length=4mm]}}
     },
   postaction=decorate}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [right=of a] (b);
    \diagram*{ (a) -- [fermion](b) };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [right=of a] (b);
    \diagram*{ (a) -- [charged boson](b) };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer!  I didn't see it until I posted my answer :)  My personal preference is to avoid overwriting the default style too much; however, I realize people might want to change things and it is up to them ultimately.  Nice modification of `with arrow`!

Comment: I finally chose the @JP-Ellis approach to create a new style instead of overwriting the existing, it's a matter of personal preference, I guess. Anyway thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: How would the command for `anti fermion` look like?

Comment: @mavzolej Does that mean the arrow direction is flipped? Did you see Níckolas Alves' answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed a little of [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t)'s answer to include antiparticles, as they seem to be built upon `with reversed arrow` instead of `with arrow` (please correct me if I'm mistaken).

```
\documentclass[review]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\tikzfeynmanset{ with arrow/.style = {
   decoration={
     markings,
     mark=at position 0.5
          with {\arrow[xshift=2mm]{Stealth[red,width=3mm,length=4mm]}}
     },
   postaction=decorate},
   with reversed arrow/.style = {
   decoration={
     markings,
     mark=at position 0.5
          with {\arrowreversed[xshift=-2mm]{Stealth[red,width=3mm,length=4mm]}}
     },
   postaction=decorate}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [right=of a] (b);
    \diagram*{ (a) -- [fermion](b) };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [right=of a] (b);
    \diagram*{ (a) -- [charged boson](b) };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [right=of a] (b);
    \diagram*{ (a) -- [anti fermion](b) };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [right=of a] (b);
    \diagram*{ (a) -- [anti charged boson](b) };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields the following diagrams:

[image: fermion]
[image: charged boson]

[image: anti fermion]
[image: anti charged boson]